# MySQL Trigger for database or user event

Tags: database, events, automation, triggers, app-startup

I'm looking for a way to run a MySQL procedure at database startup.
I can only see sql triggers for MySQL. No database and user event triggers
Are there other ways of doing this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are right when you say that triggers cannot do that. However, it is possible to achieve this via other means.

For instance you could have a program or a script that would check whether MySQL is already running. In Ubuntu that would be

```
sudo service mysql status
```

If MySQL is not active, then start it and execute the script. In Ubuntu it would look like this

```
sudo service mysql start && yourpassword | mysql -u youruser -p -e "yourcode"
```

where `yourcode` would be the procedure call. Now, you need to make sure that:

- this is a cron job and runs periodically
- MySQL is not started automatically by your OS, to make sure that if it's a reboot, then your stored procedure is being executed
- the script is safe and can only be reached by a superuser because of its awareness of your MySQL password